# method can? in javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I get an error when trying to call a method can?

> undefined method `can?' for #<#:0xa9a6d0e8>

**spr_well_types.js.erb file:**

```
    <% if can? :buttoncreate, SprWellType %>
        container.append('<div style="margin-left: 5px; float: left;" id="spr_well_type_addrowbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</div>');
    <% end %>
```

application.html.erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller], "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

assets.rb file:

```
%w( home
    spr_well_types
    spr_well_purposes 
    spr_well_constructions 
    spr_prod_programs
    spr_well_constr_details
    carpets
    spr_minefields
    spr_org_structures
    spr_layers
    mwp_plan_drillings
    planing_drill_wells
    spr_drill_rig_types
    schedules
    devise/sessions
    devise/registrations
    permissions
     ).each do |controller|
      Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js", "#{controller}.css"]
    end
```

Comment: try round brackets ``can?(:buttoncreate, SprWellType)``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `spr_well_types.js.erb` is in your assets pipeline (IE `/app/assets/javascripts/...`), you'll find that you can't use any of the object-orientated methods inside it.

As mentioned by `Martin M`, this is because *assets* are meant to be static (CSS/JS). They can be [*precompiled*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) so that they have small file sizes ([minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))) in production.

Using *paths* and other *helpers* is acceptable (these won't change), but trying to use methods such as `can?` simply won't work (they rely on dynamic data).

The simple explanation is that JS is *client-side* whilst Rails is *server-side*. JS doesn't have access to the same data as Rails, and thus cannot run methods on non-existent data.

---

**Views**

If you wanted to use this type of functionality, you'd have to put it in your *views* directory, calling it through a controller action.

This server-side javascript is not precompiled, and *does* have access to the same data as Rails. Thus, with the help of `ERB`, you can use the object-orientated methods you require.

You've not given enough context for me to know how you're calling the file, but this is an example of what you can do:

```
#app/controllers/spr_well_types_controller.rb
class SprWellTypesController < ApplicationController
   def show
     # your code here
     respond_to do |format|
       format.js #-> app/views/spr_well_types/show.js.erb
     end
   end
end

#app/views/spr_well_types/show.js.erb
<% if can? :buttoncreate, SprWellType %>
    container.append('<div style="margin-left: 5px; float: left;" id="spr_well_type_addrowbutton"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add</div>');
<% end %>
```

It must be noted that `respond_to` takes the request mime type, meaning if you want to process both `html` and `js` responses, you'll have to send the different requests using their respective method. I can explain more about that if required.

Comment: Hi Rich Peck, I'm sorry that was silent, did not have time to check what you have written. I understood your answer, it turned out to be a very expanded.
And as far as I understand format.ys it is little for another. I would not want to use it for other purposes, and fill it with lots of code with a description of the components.

Answer (score 1):

As assets are precompiled, they can't have any knowledge about the request and the session.
You have to provide this data by a program part that has this knowlege, i.e. a view.

I normally set this kind of information to global DOM variables or data-attributes in my layout (or a shared view I insert in all my layouts) and use this global data in my precompiled JS.

Ruby processing of precompiled JS files (`js.erb`) is used to calculate asset paths at compile time.